# tfs security group not access test case

Tags: tfs

Have Group Tester and Provider
Group PROVIDER only edit Bug and not access to Test Case related.
Group TESTER Only CReate and Edit BUG and Test Plan and TEst Case.

how in TFS 2012 to remove access to a PROVIDER group of test cases item?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

First lets state up front, so as to get it out of the way, that this is ridiculously dysfunctional behaviour. If you don't trust people don't give them permission at all.

That out of the way you can kind of hack this by customising the process template. If you edit the Bug to restrict the permission that can move from state "" to "New" then anyone else will get an error. This works for any work item type.

For Test Suit and Plan you need then"Create Test Plan" permission that isbin "settings|permissions" on the web access.

In TFS 2013.3 Test Suit and Test Plan are now work items so ita a little different.